# Hadoop concepts

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using hadoop to process a video using HVPI, a open source interface. However the implementation of the inputsplit, more precisely in the `isSplitableobContext (context, Path file)` method returns a `false`. By default this method returns `true` but in the current implementation there is a reason to return a`false`. If this method returns `false` I will only have one map task. If I am not wrong hadoop allocates for each input split a container that corresponds to the computational resources of a certain node of the network where a map task is executed and this node should preferably contain the data that will process. If I have a `false` I will only have an input split and consequently just one map task and this map task will run only on a cluster node.
  The big question is how a only map task take advantage from all the cpu resources of a cluster and not just a single container on a single node?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through :

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/

```
Lets try to understand what is the problem . 
1. One takes a file and divides it into fileSplits. 
2. Each split is consumed by one mapper. 
3. How do you make sure a record in the file is not split across two file splits. 
4. A record cant be ignored nor read partially. 
5. A InputFormat takes care of carefully splitting the file and handling situations when a record is split at the boundary of file splits. 
6. Hadoop has varios inpuit formats like TextInputFormat, KeyValueTextInputFormat
```

Try to find a input format which can be used for your video files or write one yourself. FileInputFormat is the base class for all.